# Issue In Hand Compiled Midi File

Tags: file, midi

I'm trying to learn how MIDI files work, and so I'm trying to hand compile a small MIDI track, writing the bytes myself. Here are all of the bytes I've done so far:

```rust
/*-----Header-Data----//-------Value-|-Description--------*/

0x4d, 0x54, 0x68, 0x64, // MThd | ASCII Header Chunk Type
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, // 6 | 32 Bit Header Size
0x00, 0x00, // 0 | 16 Bit File Format | Single Track
0x00, 0x01, // 1 | Number Of Track Chunks
0b00000000_1100010_0, // 98_0 | 98 Ticks Per Quarter Note

/*-----Track-Data----//-------Value-|-Description--------*/

0x4d, 0x54, 0x72, 0x6b, // MTrk | ASCII Track Chunk Type
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, // 4 | Track Length

/*----Event-Data---//-----Value-|-Description------*/

0x00, // 0 | Elapsed Time From The Previous Event
0b1001, // 9 | Note On Event
0b0000, // 0 | Channel 1 - Piano
0b0011_1100, // 60 | Note - Middle C
0b00100_0000, // 64 | Velocity
```

As of now, I only want to play a single note and get that working. However, the file above does not play properly (I'm on Windows).

I've been following these two websites to learn the specification:

- [http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~ich/classes/mumt306/StandardMIDIfileformat.html](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/%7Eich/classes/mumt306/StandardMIDIfileformat.html)
- http://www.ccarh.org/courses/253/handout/smf/

I would appreciate it if someone could help me in understanding why the above bytes don't work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. You missed *End of Track* event at the end of track chunk.
2. What do you mean?

   > However, the file above does not play properly

   In your file you have only *Note On* event. So you press a key and then the file immediately ends, so no sound produced. You need *Note Off* event also.

Here the simple file with one note with length of `100` MIDI ticks:

```
0x4d 0x54 0x68 0x64 // MThd
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x06
0x00 0x00
0x00 0x01
0x00 0x60

0x4d 0x54 0x72 0x6b // MTrk
0x00 0x00 0x00 0xc

0x00 0x90 0x3c 0x40 // Note On
0x64 0x80 0x3c 0x00 // Note Off
0x00 0xff 0x2f 0x00 // End of Track
```